# Заполнить двумерный ассоциативный массив

Tags: массивы, php

Добрый вечер!

Помогите, пожалуйста, с решением следующей вопроса:

имеется массив заголовков вида

```
$headers = array ('0' => 'id', '1' => 'Name', '2' => 'Balance', '3' => 'Date', '4'=> 'Region', '5' => 'Segment', '6' => 'Manager', '7' => 'Contract');
```

и массив данных вида (разумеется, в реальности данные не такие и записей больше)

```
 $content = array (
array ('0' => 'id1', '1' => 'Name1', '2' => 'balance1', '3' => 'date1', '4'=> 'region1', '5' > 'segment1', '6' => 'manager1', '7' => 'сontract1'), 
array ('0' => 'id2', '1' => 'Name2', '2' => 'balance2', '3' => 'date2', '4'=> 'region2', '5' > 'segment2', '6' => 'manager2', '7' => 'сontract2'), 
array ('0' => 'id3', '1' => 'Name3', '2' => 'balance3', '3' => 'date1', '4'=> 'region3', '5' > 'segment3', '6' => 'manager3', '7' => 'сontract3'), 
array ('0' => 'id4', '1' => 'Name4', '2' => 'balance4', '3' => 'date4', '4'=> 'region4', '5' > 'segment4', '6' => 'manager4', '7' => 'сontract4'));
```

каким образом можно получить из них массив вида

```
$data = array (
'id' => array ('0' => 'id1', '1' => 'id2', '2' => 'id3', '3' => 'id4'), 
'Name' => array ('0' => 'name1', '1' => ''name2', '2' => ''name3', '3' => ''name4'), 
'Balance' => array ('0' => 'balance1', '1' => 'balance2', '2' => 'balance3', '3' => 'balance4'), 
'Date' => array ('0' => 'date1', '1' => 'date2', '2' => 'date3', '3' => 'date4'), 
 'Region' => array ('0' => 'region1', '1' => 'region2', '2' => 'region3', '3' => 'region4'), 
 'Segment' => array ('0' => 'segment1', '1' => 'segment2', '2' => 'segment3', '3' => 'segment4'), 
'Manager' => array ('0' => 'manager1', '1' => 'manager2', '2' => 'manager3', '3' => 'manager4'), 
'Contract' => array ('0' => 'contract1', '1' => 'contract2', '2' => 'contract3', '3' => 'contract4'));
```

Понимаю что нужно использовать циклы for и foreach, но не знаю каким образом заполнить массив так как мне нужно. Помогите, пожалуйста!

код массива контент изменился:

```
    $content = array (
array(
'A{+order=S.MMStatus&how=ASC}...{width:12px}|printClientStatus2' => '3',
'Название{+order=S.Name&how=ASC}...hatch|printClientName' => 'testClient1',
'Баланс...mask|printNumber' => '150.0000',
'Дата последней рассылки...mask|printClientType' => '',
'Регион{crmclients&order=S.CRMRegionsID&how=ASC}...mask|cRegions' => '',
'Сегмент{+order=S.CRMMarcetSegmentID&how=ASC}...{width:20px}' => '',
'Менеджер{+order=S.ManagerID&how=ASC}...mask|printUser' => '2296',
'Договор|cClientRevision' => '2'),

array(
'A{+order=S.MMStatus&how=ASC}...{width:12px}|printClientStatus2' => '3',
'Название{+order=S.Name&how=ASC}...hatch|printClientName' => 'testClient2',
'Баланс...mask|printNumber' => '397.0000',
'Дата последней рассылки...mask|printClientType' => '',
'Регион{crmclients&order=S.CRMRegionsID&how=ASC}...mask|cRegions' => '',
'Сегмент{+order=S.CRMMarcetSegmentID&how=ASC}...{width:20px}' => '',
'Менеджер{+order=S.ManagerID&how=ASC}...mask|printUser' => '2296',
'Договор|cClientRevision' => '2'));
```

Comment: @project_one, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: И что значит не знаете, как заполнить? Знаете же, что хотите получить. В чём сложность? Сейчас похоже только на лень.

Comment: зачем мне тогда задавать этот вопрос здесь, если быстрее написать самому? Просто слабо понимаю подобные конструкции, поэтому и прошу совета

Answer (score 3):

```
$data = array();
foreach ($content as $line) {
    foreach ($line as $key => $val) {
        $data[$headers[$key]][] = $val;
    }
}
```

ну, видимо как-то так

[результат](http://ideone.com/TOYmld)

ЗЫ благодарю анонимных минусующих, ваша лаконичность неподражаема :)

Comment: благодарю за ответ

Comment: к сожалению задача осложнилась тем что массив $line ассоциативный, т.е. ключи у него и у $heders разные. Как быть в таком случае?

Comment: если ключи разные, то эти массивы невозможно связать, пример с новыми данными в вопрос добавьте.

Comment: @project_one добавьте актуальный код к вопросу (текущий не удаляйте) возможно через сортировку получится что-то придумать, хотя это конечно костылик под конкретную ситуацию, который развалится при изменении ключей

Comment: добавил актуальный код

Comment: измените ключи массива $headers соответственно измененным ключам массива $content 

(пр. первая пара вместо '0' => 'id' станет 'A{+order=S.MMStatus&how=ASC}...{width:12px}|printClientStatus2' => 'id')

Answer (score 2):

```
$headers = [
    '0' => 'id', 
    '1' => 'Name', 
    '2' => 'Balance', 
    '3' => 'Date', 
    '4' => 'Region', 
    '5' => 'Segment', 
    '6' => 'Manager', 
    '7' => 'Contract'
  ];

$content = [ 
  [
    '0' => 'id1', 
    '1' => 'Name1', 
    '2' => 'balance1', 
    '3' => 'date1', 
    '4' => 'region1', 
    '5' => 'segment1', 
    '6' => 'manager1', 
    '7' => 'сontract1'
  ], 
  [
    '0' => 'id2', 
    '1' => 'Name2', 
    '2' => 'balance2', 
    '3' => 'date2', 
    '4' => 'region2', 
    '5' > 'segment2', 
    '6' => 'manager2', 
    '7' => 'сontract2'
  ], 
];

$data = array();
foreach ($headers as $key => $line) {
    $data[$line] = array_column($content, $key);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

Вывод:

```
Array
(
    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => id1
            [1] => id2
        )

    [Name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name1
            [1] => Name2
        )

    [Balance] => Array
        (
            [0] => balance1
            [1] => balance2
        )

    [Date] => Array
        (
            [0] => date1
            [1] => date2
        )

    [Region] => Array
        (
            [0] => region1
            [1] => region2
        )

    [Segment] => Array
        (
            [0] => segment1
            [1] => 
        )

    [Manager] => Array
        (
            [0] => manager1
            [1] => manager2
        )

    [Contract] => Array
        (
            [0] => сontract1
            [1] => сontract2
        )

)
```